# Objective-C "<...>" notation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, syntax

I'm reading through More iPhone Programming 3, and I cannot remember what the <> notation is.  I know it's to conform to Protocols for a class, but I'm not sure what it is in this example talking about NSFetchedResultsController in the Core Data section.  Here is the code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo` simply means `sectionInfo` is some object (indicated by `id`) that conforms to the [`NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

By declaring the variable as a type that conforms to this protocol, its `numberOfObjects` property is guaranteed to be available to use, unless it turns out the object doesn't conform to the protocol in which case you get a crash.